# Prevent name collisions on form value flattening?

Tags: forms

> The element's name property is declared in the $form array, at the
>   very end of the array tree. For example, if an element in the form
>   tree was structured like this: 
>   $form['account_settings']['username'] ?>
>
> ...then that element's name property is 'username'--this is the key it
>   will be available under in $form_state['values'], in your validation
>   and submission functions, as the form code flattens the array in this
>   fashion before it passes the key/value pairs. NOTE: if you wish to
>   have the full tree structure passed to $form_state['values'], this is
>   possible, and will be discussed later.

-[Source](https://drupal.org/node/751826)

So, for example, if you have this:

```
$form['details']['admin'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Only admin can view'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('admin', 0),
  );
```

You see that you'd be using variable_get('admin', 0);

So what's to prevent naming collisions? Say you have another setting:

```
$form['more_details']['admin'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => t('Only admin can view'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('admin', 0),
      );
```

If anyone has a clear explanation as to how this "flattening" works, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

While it's good practice to use unique field names in your form, you can use the [#tree](https://drupal.org/node/48643) property to preserve the group nesting of parent -> same child name there.

```
$form['#tree'] = TRUE;
```

That will preserve the nesting of group -> field values in the form `$form_state['values']` so instead of being flattened it will be

```
$form_state['values']['details']['admin'] = 'foo';
```

and

```
$form_state['values']['more_details']['admin'] = 'bar';
```

Comment: True, but when it comes to using variable_get after you save the form, what will the difference in variable names be?

Comment: @AlxVallejo, the variable will be an array with nested values.